# USB Device Release

Tags: python, pyusb

I am currently working on PyUSB. As I am new to USB, I don’t know, how can I do the following.

I have successfully connected to my USB Device hardware from Python PyUSB. In the code I required to reset the USB Device hardware.
Which I did by sending a command to the hardware. Now after hardware reset, I want to release the current USB device from Python PyUSB.
And then I want to connect again to the USB Device Hardware after it come back from reset.

Please let me know, how can I release the USB Device Connection and interfaces etc so that I can reconnect?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you, please, found your answer ?

Answer (score 6):

```
my_device = usb.core.find(...)
```

...

```
# necessary to allow further claim_interface calls
#   (bulk read), generally not needed
usb.util.dispose_resources(my_device)
```

Comment: "this function releases all internal resources allocated by the device, like device handle and interface policy."
https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/ffe6faf42c6ad273880b0b464b9bbf44c1d4b2e9/usb/util.py#L206

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from usb.core import find as finddev
dev = finddev(idVendor=0x1234, idProduct=0x5678)
dev.reset()
```

Comment: Not in the business anymore, but the `reset` command also does hardware reset in addition to resources disposal as seen [here](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/ffe6faf42c6ad273880b0b464b9bbf44c1d4b2e9/usb/core.py#L913). This might be indeed what the author of the question wants.

Answer (score 0):

While the above answer is perfectly valid, I've encountered multiple times when resetting an USB device is not sufficient.

A good way to deal with those is to remove power from the USB controller, forcing them to restart as if they were plugged out / plugged in.

TL;DR: I've built a small python script to reset usb devices or usb controllers.
See [this link](https://github.com/netinvent/usb_resetter)
worked for me where no other reset solution worked (some bad USB UPSes)
Usage:

```
usb_reset --reset
#or
usb_reset --list && usb_reset -d 1234:1234
```

Original idea using bash comes from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/290519/983734)

```
    for i in /sys/bus/pci/drivers/[uoex]hci_hcd/*:*; do
      [ -e "$i" ] || continue
      echo "Resetting ${i%/*}/${i##*/}"
      echo "${i##*/}" > "${i%/*}/unbind"
      echo "${i##*/}" > "${i%/*}/bind"
    done
```